# Having trouble updating multiple accumulators across a single loop

Tags: arrays, swift, function

This is a function that accepts input "change" and returns a breakdown of how many quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies to give back to a customer.

My approach: let's say change is $0.62

1. Check is change > quarters. If yes, subtract $0.25. Each time a quarter is subtracted, add 1 to the quarter accumulator. Repeat until quarters can no longer be subtracted from the remaining change value. (This should result in 2 quarters)
2. Remaining change is $0.12 after this step
3. Move onto dimes - each time a dime is subtracted from the change, add 1 to the dime accumulator
4. Repeat for nickels and pennies

While I can easily iterate across the coinTray array and subtract the values, how do I indicate that once the array moves to the next item, switch to the next accumulator and begin adding to it?

I've solved it here without the use of a loop, but is there a more efficient way to do this?

```
func breakdown(change: Double) -> String {

    var coinTray: [Double] = [0.25, 0.10, 0.05, 0.01]
    var totalChange = change

    var quarters = 0
    var dimes = 0
    var nickels = 0
    var pennies = 0

    while totalChange >= coinTray[0] {
        totalChange -= coinTray[0]
        quarters += 1
    }

    while totalChange >= coinTray[1] {
        totalChange -= coinTray[1]
        dimes += 1
    }

    while totalChange >= coinTray[2] {
        totalChange -= coinTray[2]
        nickels += 1
    }

    while totalChange >= coinTray[3] {
        totalChange -= coinTray[3]
        pennies += 1
    }

return "You should have \(quarters) quarter(s), \(dimes) dime(s), \(nickels) nickel(s), and \(pennies) penny/ies."

}
```

Comment: "_I've solved it here without the use of a loop_", errr... you seem to be using 4.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri True, there are 4 while loops. But I'm wondering if there is a way to clean those up into a single loop since everything's being repeated except for the accumulator.

Comment: How about without any? Like this answer posted below ? :)

Comment: I have edited the answer. I think i understand what you were looking for. But this is not practical for dynamic number of variables in which case you'll have to use an array of tuples which is complicated for such a simple thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this does the same thing without a loop.

```
func breakDown(change: Double) -> String {
    var coinTray: [Double] = [0.25, 0.10, 0.05, 0.01]
    var totalChange = change

    var quarters = 0
    var dimes    = 0
    var nickels  = 0
    var pennies  = 0

    quarters    = Int(totalChange/coinTray[0])
    totalChange = totalChange.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: coinTray[0])
    dimes       = Int(totalChange/coinTray[1])
    totalChange = totalChange.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: coinTray[1])
    nickels     = Int(totalChange/coinTray[2])
    totalChange = totalChange.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: coinTray[2])
    pennies     = Int(totalChange * 100)

    return "You should have \(quarters) quarter(s), \(dimes) dime(s), \(nickels) nickel(s), and \(pennies) penny/ies."
}
```

Edit: Seems like OP wants this answer.

```
var coinTray: [Double] = [0.25, 0.10, 0.05, 0.01]

var quarters = 0
var dimes   = 0
var nickels = 0
var pennies = 0

var coins = [quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies]

func breakDown(change: Double) -> String {

    var totalChange = change
    for i in 0..<coinTray.count {
        coins[i] = Int(totalChange/coinTray[i])
        totalChange = totalChange.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: coinTray[i])
    }
    return "You should have \(quarters) quarter(s), \(dimes) dime(s), \(nickels) nickel(s), and \(pennies) penny/ies."
}
```